# Mock Stripe API with jest in Node typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, stripe-payments

I'm stuck at trying to mock the Stripe API in order to perform tests. I have little experience with mocking functions with jest but I have already done a deep search on how to mock Stripe's API but non seems to be working.

My file structure is the following:

```
src/payment-gateways/stripe.ts

import Stripe from 'stripe'
import { PAYMENT_STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY } from '../config'

const stripe = new Stripe(PAYMENT_STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
})

export default stripe
```

Then on my `stripe.test.ts` I call my API endpoints in order that in the middle of the logic it creates a stripe customer.

What I have already tried was:

```
src/tests/__mocks__/stripe.ts

export class Stripe {}
const stripe = jest.fn(() => new Stripe())


export default stripe
```

```
src/...../stripe.test.ts

import { Stripe } from 'stripe'

Stripe.prototype.customers = {
    create: jest.fn(() => ({
              id: 1,
           })),
  } as unknown as Stripe.CustomersResource

//And also tried this without __mocks__

jest.mock('../../../../../../payment-gateways/stripe', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => ({
    customers: {
      create: jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
          id: '1',
        })
      ),
    },
  }))
})

describe('stripe workflow', ()=> {
   it('creates a customer', async () => {
      await apollo.mutate...
   .
   .
   .
 })
})
```

But I keep getting the error `[[GraphQLError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined]]` both methods.

I guess I'm missing something on the way jest works with mocks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Getting the same problem :(

Comment: Not yet, havent look at this again since I'm working on a different project. But if I ever solve this I tag you

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by mocking out the implementation of Stripe:

```
const mockedCustomerCreate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('stripe', () => {
  const customers = jest.fn();
  // @ts-ignore
  customers.create = (...args) = mockedCustomerCreate(...args);

  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    customers
  }));
});

describe('foo', () => {
  test('bar', async () => {
    mockedCustomerCreate.mockResolvedValue({});
    
    // your test stuff

    expect(mockedCustomerCreate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
})
```

Couple things to note about this method:

- the `// @ts-ignore` is necessary to force the typing
- the `customers.create` needs to be wrapped in another function otherwise jest will complain
- you will need to do something similar for each function you use on the Stripe object

Comment: @vwos Take a look.
Thanks I will give it a try when I wrap up again this issue. I will leave some feedback

Answer (score 1):

Mocking Stripe API in node has been a real pain so I hope this comment is useful to someone. I have improved on @MrDiggles answer. I'm mocking out `paymentIntent.create` method, but the theory is the same. Really I've just made the nested mock functions return implicitly and removed a few unnecessary lines, plus satisfied TS complier. The key part here is the `create: (...args: any) => mockPaymentsIntentsCreate(...args) as unknown,` which allows the mock to be accessed outside of the `jest.mock` scope (and can therefore have behaviour changed for different tests, as demonstrated), but still be hoisted and so is run before `stripe` is imported in the code under test. I'm actually not 100% sure how this even works; using `create: mockPaymentsIntentsCreate` instead would give you a `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockPaymentsIntentsCreate' before initialization`. Hopefully someone cleverer than me can answer that!

`index.ts`

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...', {
    apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
});

export const createPaymentIntent = async (parameters: Stripe.PaymentIntentCreateParams) => stripe.paymentIntents.create(parameters);
```

`index.spec.ts`

```
import { createPaymentIntent } from '../../src/stripe-client';

const mockPaymentsIntentsCreate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('stripe', () => jest.fn(() => ({
    paymentIntents: {
        create: (...args: any) => mockPaymentsIntentsCreate(...args) as unknown,
    },
})));

describe('stripe-client', () => {
    test('create payment intent happy path', async () => {
        const paymentIntentsCreateResponse = { id: '123' };
        mockPaymentsIntentsCreate.mockResolvedValueOnce(paymentIntentsCreateResponse);

        const result = await createPaymentIntent({
            amount: 100,
            currency: 'gbp',
        });

        expect(result).toBe(paymentIntentsCreateResponse);
    });

    test('create payment intent unhappy path', async () => {
        const paymentIntentsCreateResponse = 'oops';
        mockPaymentsIntentsCreate.mockRejectedValueOnce(paymentIntentsCreateResponse);

        await expect(createPaymentIntent({
            amount: 100,
            currency: 'gbp',
        })).rejects.toBe(paymentIntentsCreateResponse);
    });
});
```